# AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights: filter_log_events Always Returns a nextToken and Never Completes a Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to query AWS CloudWatch Logs using Boto3's filter_log_events method in Python, intending to retrieve logs for about 100,000 log streams in batches of 100. The log group I am querying is /aws/batch/job.

However, I am experiencing a peculiar issue where every response from filter_log_events contains a nextToken, causing the loop to run indefinitely for a single batch. This indicates that there are more logs to retrieve, but it never seems to finish a batch, and it's impractical with my volume of log streams.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

python

```
import time

log_stream_name_for_event = []
request_count = []
events_captured = 0
session = boto3.Session()
cloudwatch_client = session.client('logs')
batch_size = 100

for i in range(0, len(log_stream_names), batch_size):
    log_stream_batch = log_stream_names[i:i + batch_size]
    params = {
        'logGroupName': '/aws/batch/job',
        'logStreamNames': log_stream_batch,
        'filterPattern': "%downloader\/request_count%",
    }
    events = []
    while True:
        try:
            response = cloudwatch_client.filter_log_events(**params)
            events.extend(response.get("events", []))
            if 'nextToken' in response:
                params['nextToken'] = response['nextToken']
            else:
                break
        except boto3.exceptions.botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ThrottlingException':
                print("Throttling Exception occurred. Waiting and then retrying...")
                time.sleep(10)
            else:
                raise
    # ... [Processing the events]
```

To be noted, the method doesn't throw any 400 or 500 errors, nor does it throw a ThrottlingException.

Here are my concerns and questions:

Why does filter_log_events continuously return a nextToken, never allowing a batch to complete?
Is there a limitation or issue with filter_log_events that could be causing this behavior, especially at this scale of log streams?
Are there any workarounds or alternative approaches to handle this scale of log streams effectively and efficiently?
I can't use subscription filters to send the log data to opensearch until my boss gets back from vacation so a workaround would be fantastic.
Thank you in advance for your insights and suggestions!

To address this issue, I attempted to run the loop without leveraging nextToken, with the intention that any log streams not gathered in one iteration could be captured in the subsequent ones until there were no remaining log streams in the batch. Regrettably, this approach proved ineffective as the filter seemingly failed to identify the events within the residual log streams, despite their presence.

I have meticulously verified all the logs and can confirm that the "request_count" events do indeed exist within them. However, the intended events still remain undetected and uncollected during the iteration, leaving me perplexed and in search of a resolution or an alternative approach to efficiently handle the collection of events from a substantial number of log streams.